# Angular routing isnt work in asp.net mvc4, why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new with Angular & try to implement routing in asp.net mvc 4 application. My controller is work & routing make an update but dont load information to the view. Anybody know why?

**JobParsing.js**

```
var JobParsing = angular.module('JobParsing', []);

JobParsing.controller('LandingPageController', LandingPageController);

var configFunction = function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/routeOne', {
            templateUrl: 'home/one',
            controller: 'LandingPageController'
        })
        .when('/routeTwo', {
            templateUrl: 'home/two',
            controller: 'LandingPageController'
        });
};
configFunction.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];

JobParsing.config(configFunction);
```

**LandingPageController.js**

```
var LandingPageController = function($scope) {
    $scope.models = {
        helloAngular: 'I work! Hello!'
    };
};

LandingPageController.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

**_Layout**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="JobParsing" data-ng-controller="LandingPageController">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title data-ng-bind="models.helloAngular"></title>
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()

    <input type="text" data-ng-model="models.helloAngular" />
    <h1>{{models.helloAngular}}</h1>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="/#/routeOne">Route One</a></li>
        <li><a href="/#/routeTwo">Route Two</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div data-ng-view=""></div>

    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/JobParsing")
</body>
</html>
```

**One.cshtml ( Two.cshtml identical )**

```
<h2>One</h2>
```

Comment: Is your One.cshtml file placed in Views/Home/One.cshtml?

Comment: I would suggest the use of partialviews. I tried it and works without problems.

Comment: @DaniCE yes, youre right

Comment: @blacai partial view isnt work too

Comment: If you define partialviews like this in the routeconfig:             `when('/myapp/:partialViewId', {
                templateUrl: function (params) { return '/MainController/Action/' + params.partialViewId; },
            }) ` and your MainController defines the method with the `PartialViewResult` should work.

Comment: Did you check the updated solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get why you use the .$inject. You can use the 'normal' [injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18698963/use-of-inject-in-angular-js-in-controllers)

Here you can see a solution using partialviews:

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html ng-app="JobParsingApp" ng-controller="lpCtrl">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>{{test}}</h1>
        @RenderBody()
        <input type="text" ng-model="models.helloAngular"
            ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }" />
        <h1>{{models.helloAngular()}}</h1>
        <br />
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#/routeOne">Route One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/routeTwo">Route Two</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div ng-view>

        </div>

    </div>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/JobParsing")
</body>
</html>
```

**JobParsing.js**

```
var JobParsing = angular.module('JobParsingApp', ['ngRoute', 'JobParsingApp.LandingPageController']);

JobParsing.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/routeOne', {
                templateUrl: '/Home/One'
                //controller: 'LandingPageController' <-- they are partial, you don't need
        }).
        when('/routeTwo', {
                templateUrl: '/Home/Two'
                //controller: 'LandingPageController' <-- same... adapt your routing when using complete views.
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
    }
]);
```

**LandingPageController.js**

```
var LandingPageController = angular.module('JobParsingApp.LandingPageController', []);

LandingPageController.controller('lpCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
   $scope.test = 'test data';

   var _helloAngular = 'I work! Hello!';
   $scope.models = {
      helloAngular: function (newMsg) {
         if (angular.isDefined(newMsg)) {
           _helloAngular = newMsg;
         }
         return _helloAngular;
      }
   };
}]);
```

**BundleConfig.cs**

...

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/JobParsing").Include(
    "~/Scripts/JobParsing/LandingPageController.js",
    "~/Scripts/JobParsing/JobParsing.js"
));
```

...

**HomeController.cs**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public PartialViewResult One()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }

    public PartialViewResult Two()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
<h1>Index</h1>
```

**One.cshtml**

```
<h2>One</h2>
```

**Two.cshtml**

```
<h2>Two</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference a file in `templateUrl`

```
templateUrl: 'home/two.html'
```

Comment: I cant because using HomeController.cs where have ActionResult One()

Comment: What is you controller returning?

Comment: asp.net mvc controller return One.cshtml

Comment: you need to return html.