# View is not displaying after Homecontroller is executed in asp.net mvc

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to navigating from login page to Home page but it is not navigating to login page even though it is hitting HomeController, here i used angularjs http.get service for navigating.

I have verified RouteConfig settings, but am unable to find the problem where it is.

Below is route config

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

angular code

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module("AngularApp", []);
    app.service("loginservice", function ($http) {

        this.Checkuser = function (UserName, password) {
            return $http({
                method: "Post",
                url: "Login/LoginUserAuth/",
                data: { UserName: UserName, password: password }
            });
        }
        this.NavigateToHome = function (UserName) {
            return $http({
                method: "get",
                url: "Home/Index"
            });
        }
    });

    app.controller("LoginController", function ($scope, $http, loginservice) {
        $scope.Checkuser = function () {
            var checkresult = loginservice.Checkuser($scope.username, $scope.password);
            checkresult.success(function (dataFromServer, status, headers, config) {
                //alert(dataFromServer);
                if (dataFromServer == '"Login Success"') {
                    var NavigateToHome = loginservice.NavigateToHome($scope.username);
                }
                else {
                    alert('Wrong UserName or Password');
                }
            });
            checkresult.error(function () {
                alert('Error in Login');
            });
        }
    });
}
())
```

Home controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: $http won't redirect you to any page, it'll just return a promise. use window.location.href = 'yoururl' inside javascript

Comment: if you are using $routeProvider then use $location.path('url')

Comment: but it is hitting the controller method, but it is not showing the view

Comment: its because of you are making ajax to that controller action,,,

Comment: instead of $http call put this.NavigateToHome = function (UserName) {
            window.location = '/home';
        }

Comment: `$get` is not helpful in this situation.  you are asking the server to 'get' the view from the server, but once it has done so, you aren't doing anything with that view.   you should be navigating rather than getting the data.  as a side note, why are you using angular to try to load an MVC controller anyway?

Comment: @user3523336 have you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: Sorry Pankaj, still am facing an issue, before i haven't use the routeprovider, now i am trying with routeprovider

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26487914/angular-routing-isnt-work-in-asp-net-mvc4-why

Comment: Hi Andrew, am implementing sample angular js application with asp.net mvc, I just beginner in angularjs, doing all experiments.

Comment: Hi Andrew, can you please give me the suggestion/tips to implement/learn angularjs with asp.net mvc

Comment: other one https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/03/25/bootstrapping-angularjs-applications-with-server-side-data-from-aspnet-mvc

Comment: I have used windows.location for navigating page