# Receiving "Unknown provider: UploadProvider" error using ng-file-upload

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-file-upload

I'm attempting to use the ng-file-upload directive (https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) to add file-uploading functionality to my project, but keep getting this error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/$injector/unpr?p0=UploadProvider%20%3C-%20Upload%20%3C-%20ExperimentController
at Error (native)
at http://localhost:8000/static/editor/js/angular.min.js:6:416
at http://localhost:8000/static/editor/js/angular.min.js:40:409
at Object.d [as get] (http://localhost:8000/static/editor/js/angular.min.js:38:394)
at http://localhost:8000/static/editor/js/angular.min.js:40:483
at d (http://localhost:8000/static/editor/js/angular.min.js:38:394)
at e (http://localhost:8000/static/editor/js/angular.min.js:39:161)
at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:8000/static/editor/js/angular.min.js:39:310)
at http://localhost:8000/static/editor/js/angular.min.js:80:313
at A.link (http://localhost:8000/static/editor/js/angular-route.min.js:7:268) <div ng-view="" ng-show="main.results==null" class="ng-scope">
```

I'm including the correct files in my index.html:

```
<script src="/static/editor/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/editor/js/ng-file-upload-shim.js"></script>
<script src="/static/editor/js/ng-file-upload.js"></script>
```

I'm declaring it my module:

```
(function() {
    angular
        .module('myApp', [
            'ngRoute',
            'ngAnimate',
            'ngCookies',
            'ngFileUpload'
    ]);
})();
```

But when I attempt to inject it into my controller, it throws the above error:

```
(function() {
    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .controller('myController', myController);

    myController.$inject = ['$routeParams',
        '$compile',
        '$scope',
        '$interval',
        'Upload'];


function myController($routeParams,
    $compile,
    $scope,
    $interval,
    Upload) {
....
```

I'm using Angular 1.4.6, and ng-file-upload 9.0.14. I downloaded the files manually, and included the indicated .js files in my project directory. Are there maybe some extra dependencies that are included via bower or npm that I'm missing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE: Viewing the ng-file-upload directive's live demo page with AngularJS 1.4.6 (https://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/#/1.4.6) also causes numerous errors, so this might just be an incompatibility with 1.4.6 and the lastest version of ng-file-upload.

Comment: You could get some work around from here https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/issues/45

Comment: I don't know if it is related but check out this answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/29813551/4194436

Comment: You need to inject the module: `angular.module('myApp',  ['angularFileUpload'])....`

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried all these things, including the work-around in the first link (which is what got me to my current code state, actually). Also, 'angularFileUpload' is actually a different directive (again, I'm using ng-file-upload -- please see the link in my initial question)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to inject unknown service called "Upload", if you mean the upload service of ng-file-upload you need to inject "ngFileUpload" instead of "Upload".

```
  myController.$inject = ['$routeParams',
        '$compile',
        '$scope',
        '$interval',
        'ngFileUpload'];

function myController($routeParams,
    $compile,
    $scope,
    $interval,
    ngFileUpload) {
....
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, too -- the actual documentation and examples, however, say to use 'Upload,' and poking around the source code verifies this is, in fact, the correct injection name.

Comment: right, did you inject ngFileUpload to you module? var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngFileUpload']);