# Pass $http service in AngularJS to normal javascript function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-services

I am using Jquery widget inside a AngularJS directive.

```
App.directive('eff',['$http',function($http) {
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        $('#Widget').charts(
            getWidget(),
            function (chart) {
                // generate chart widget...
            }
        });
    }
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: link
    };
}]);

// Normal JS function 
function getWidget(){
    // return widget data
}
```

Now I want to use the `$http` service form AngularJS inside `getWidget` function to load data from server.

Is it possible to pass the `$http` service object to `getWidget` method and load data?

Comment: Even if, the function couldn't return data fetched from a remote server synchronously. Though check the Angular docs for `inject`.

Comment: why do you need to do that, why you cant keep that function in angular scope.. ??

Comment: @entre I did not understand what you just asked clearly .Did you mean that to bind the function to AngularJS Application('App')? Like **App.getWidget(//code here)**

Comment: I am asking you the purpose, why are you doing it.. passing $http to some function outside angular... if its outside angular, use jquery $.ajax or best would be to get it inside angular controller

Comment: So your question is "how do I pass an argument to a function"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Gant here is what you can try.

```
  function getWidget(){
   var $http = angular.injector(['ng']).get('$http');
    $http.get("path"); //
  }
```

Comment: you mean you can use angular's http service outside angular app? why not post an answer then? maybe then i can also learn something new.

Comment: @Gant read this and docs
$inject Property Annotation
To allow the minifiers to rename the function parameters and still be able to inject the right services, the function needs to be annotated with the $inject property. The $inject property is an array of service names to inject.
[also this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18698963/use-of-inject-in-angular-js-in-controllers)

Comment: `angular.injector(['ng']).get('$http');`, I don't see why you wouldn't wrap it into a service though, so it'd be a bad answer. Wouldn't know about minification, moved on to ng2 and then React a while ago.

Comment: WHAT op want
 Pass $http service in AngularJS to **normal javascript function**
not a service

Comment: thanks i tested your suggestion and yes it it possible, never did it before but still it's involving angular and i thought OP don't want to involve angular it all i will update my answer, again thanks @Gant

Answer (score 0):

You can get the service like this. This will reduce the number of errors which may occur due to multiple angular instances

```
function getService(param) {
//use the root angular element id over here
  var applicationEl = angular.element('[YourRootElementReference]'),
      myInjector;
  param = '$http';
  if (applicationEl) {
    try {
            myInjector = applicationEl.injector(); //this will fetch you the injector
            if (myInjector) {
               return myInjector.get(param); // return the service
            }
        } catch (e) {
           return undefined;
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function doStuff(){
      angular.element(document).injector().invoke(function($compile , service1 , $http) {
          //do remainder of the stuff here        
      });
}
```

I hope this helps