# Custom directive with $http injection angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ajax

I want to make a widget by using angularjs's custom directive, but stuck somewhere injecting $http service in it.

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.directive('users',function($scope,$http){

  return {


  $http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  .then(function(response) {

     $scope.user = response.data;
   })
  }

})
```

Any thought how can it be done? I know above code doesn't work but I have no clue how to continue.

Comment: Your function should return an object with the properties of your directive (`restrict`, `template`, etc.). Please read the directive tutorial on Angular website. If you need to execute some code when the directive binds, it can be done in the`link` method.

Comment: @Impworks are there compulsory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should probably look like:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.directive('users', users);

users.$inject = ['$http'];

function users($http){    
  return {
     restrict: 'E', // if it's element
     template: '<div><ul><li ng-repeat="user in users">{{user.name}}</li></ul>{{user}}</div>',  // example template
     link: function($scope){
        $http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
          .then(function(response) {
             $scope.users = response.data;
          });
     }
  };
}
```

Here's a working jsbin: http://jsbin.com/qepibukovu/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: http://jsbin.com/jaweqihoyu/edit?html,js,console,output nope it's not working. why you no need ng-repeat?

Comment: There should be one more bracket '}'. Check it now as above.

Comment: what if I want to display the user's name in a `<li>`, I can do the same like usual?

Comment: why do u use $inject? what's the problem with my injection above? like just pass $http as a param.

Comment: @NingSia you can read more here https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#manual-annotating-for-dependency-injection

Comment: @NingSia  when you declare your dependencies explicitly , you can minify your js : more informations here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18698963/use-of-inject-in-angular-js-in-controllers