# Error with Angularjs 1.5.8 script: how to write correct code?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, jsp, servlets

I'm having some problems on Angular 1.5.8
This is my Script:

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MyController', function($scope,$http) {
        $scope.getDataFromServer = function() {
                $http({
                        method : 'GET',
                        url : 'javaAngularJS'
                }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        $scope.person = data;
                     // this callback will be called asynchronously
                        // when the response is available
                }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                        // or server returns response with an error status.
                });

        };
};
```

but when i call it, i get this error on chrome console:

```
angular.js:13920 Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/ng/areq?p0=MyController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at angular.js:38
    at sb (angular.js:1892)
    at Pa (angular.js:1902)
    at angular.js:10330
    at ag (angular.js:9451)
    at p (angular.js:9232)
    at g (angular.js:8620)
    at angular.js:8500
    at angular.js:1763
    at m.$eval (angular.js:17682)
```

This is my code in jsp:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
                    <div ng-controller="MyController">
                        <button ng-click="getDataFromServer()">Fetch data from server</button>
                        <p>First Name : {{person.firstName}} </p>
                        <p>Last Name : {{person.lastName}} </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Obviously i have Person Class and added servlet path in web.xml. I think my problem is my bad code in Angular. What's the correct way to write controller and function in js file? THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a couple of things. Beside the `);` at the end of your Angular code, you have forgot to add dependencies as well. Try this:

```
//create module
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

//add controler to module
app.controller('MyController', MyController);

//add dependecies
MyController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];

//controller function
function MyController($scope,$http) {
        $scope.getDataFromServer = function() {
                $http({
                        method : 'GET',
                        url : 'javaAngularJS'
                }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        $scope.person = data;
                     // this callback will be called asynchronously
                        // when the response is available
                }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                        // or server returns response with an error status.
                });

        };
}
```

**EDIT:**

For more details on `$inject`, you can check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18698963/use-of-inject-in-angular-js-in-controllers). Code above can be written like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope,$http) {
        $scope.getDataFromServer = function() {
                $http({
                        method : 'GET',
                        url : 'javaAngularJS'
                }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        $scope.person = data;
                     // this callback will be called asynchronously
                        // when the response is available
                }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                        // or server returns response with an error status.
                });

        };
}]);
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. Can you explain me "app.controller('MyController', MyController);" and "MyController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http']"? Never seen before.

Comment: I will edit the question to the other option.

Comment: ok thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

you are missing ) at the end of code snippet, fix that and it should work fine.