# AngularJS: passing in variables into a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created a service that has a method that does a simple calculation.  It takes a value and squares it.  However, I'm getting an error saying that square is undefined so I'm guessing I'm passing in the value incorrectly.

jsfid: http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/19107/

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

/* function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
} */

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope, CalcService) {
var cheese = CalcService.square(2);
  $scope.value = cheese;
  
}]);

myApp.service('CalcService', function(x){
   this.square = function(x) {

   var y = x*x;
      return y;
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Hello, {{value}}!
</div>
```

Comment: In your controller you aren't injecting the CalcService, and you're adding the parameter `x` to the service function. You should remove it. Check this updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/19114/

Comment: Ah ok, syntax error, so the injection happens in the beginning with the  quotes, why the need to put it in the function param then?

Comment: This is for file minification. Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18698963/i-dont-understand-the-use-of-inject-in-controllers. You can write it like `myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, CalcService) {}` but this won't work when you minify your file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you missed to inject service to controller in proper way check the snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp">

  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Hello, {{value}}!
</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>

<script>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

/* function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
} */

myApp.service('CalcService', function(){
   this.square = function(x) {

   var y = x*x;
      return y;
   }
});
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope','CalcService', function($scope, CalcService) {
var cheese = CalcService.square(2);
  $scope.value = cheese;
  
}]);


</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

See here you missed `CalcService` inject in controller initialization:

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'CalcService', function($scope, CalcService) {
var cheese = CalcService.square(2);
$scope.value = cheese;

}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed to inject '***CalcService***'.

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope','**CalcService**', function($scope, **CalcService**) {
}]);

Answer (score 0):

Your service should be something like:

```
myApp.service('CalcService', function(){
return {
    square: function (x) {
        var y = x*x;
        return y;
    }
}});
```

And you should inject service in your controller.